Calendar ‘Print’ not showing grid lines and Text light gray
When clicking the ‘Print’ button the text shows as light gray for a calendar event when I print to a printer or print as PDF. Is this a fix that can be done in the HTML/CSS code or is this due to the print settings itself and nothing can be done about it?
I am providing the HTML/CSS code and a couple of screenshots: one of what the page looks like and what it looks like when printing to PDF.
Have tried using @media print by testing the text '12p Test' which is a.fc-daygrid-event selector but that doesn't change the text to black text.
What the page in the app looks like currently:

After clicking Print button and what it looks like printing to PDF. Text is gray and a little hard to read

HTML
 <div class="card">
   <div class="card-header d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
    <div class="d-flex align-items-center">
    <h2 class="mr-3">Calendar</h2>
    <lf-timezone-selector
        *ngIf="jwt"
        (changed)="timezoneChanged($event);" [(ngModel)]="timezone" ngDefaultControl> 
  </lf-timezone-selector>
</div>

<div class="d-flex">
    <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" (click)="print()">
        Print
    </button>
    <lf-google-signin *ngIf="jwt"
                      [selectedCalendarName]="calendarName"
                      (sendSignOut)="handleSignOut()"
                      (sendSignIn)="handleSignIn()"
                      (showCalendarSelectorDialog)="showCalendarSelectorDialog()"
    ></lf-google-signin>
 </div>
 </div>
 <div class="card-body text-center">
  <full-calendar class="lf-full-calendar"
               id="calendar-container"
               #calendarComponent
                  [options]="calendarOptions"></full-calendar>
</div>
 </div> 
   <mat-tab-group>
    <mat-tab label="Current Invoices">
        <ng-template matTabContent>
            <lf-unit-invoices-table #unitOutstandingInvoicesTable
                                    
      (emitReloadUnitBalance)="this.emitReloadUnitBalance.emit($event);"
                                    [unitId]="this.unitId"
                                    [context]="'unpaid'"
            ></lf-unit-invoices-table>
        </ng-template>
    </mat-tab>
    <mat-tab label="Recurring Templates">
        <lf-unit-recurring-charges-table [unitId]="this.unitId"></lf-unit-recurring- 
  charges-table>
    </mat-tab>
    <mat-tab label="Account History">
        <ng-template matTabContent>
            <div *ngIf="hasUnitReadAccess" class="px-4 pt-2">
                <mat-slide-toggle (change)="onCurrentOwnerToggle($event)">
                    <span class="text-secondary">Current Owner</span>
                    <i matTooltip="Toggle viewing account history for current owner, or 
     for all 
             owners." class="fa fa-info-circle p-1 text-secondary"></i>
                </mat-slide-toggle>
            </div>
            <lf-unit-account-history-table
                #unitAccountHistory
                [unitId]="this.unitId"></lf-unit-account-history-table>
        </ng-template>
    </mat-tab>
    <mat-tab label="All Invoices">
        <ng-template matTabContent>
            <lf-unit-invoices-table #unitAllInvoicesTable 
        (emitReloadUnitBalance)="this.emitReloadUnitBalance.emit($event);"
                                    [unitId]="this.unitId"
                                    [context]="'all'"
            ></lf-unit-invoices-table>
        </ng-template>
    </mat-tab>
    <mat-tab label="All Payments">
        <ng-template matTabContent>
            <lf-unit-payments-table [unitId]="this.unitId"></lf-unit-payments-table>
        </ng-template>
    </mat-tab>
    <mat-tab *ngIf="jwt.superUser">
        <ng-template mat-tab-label>
            Credits
            <app-super-star></app-super-star>
        </ng-template>
        <ng-template matTabContent>
            <lf-unit-credits-table 
          (emitReloadUnitBalance)="this.emitReloadUnitBalance.emit($event);"
                                   [unitId]="this.unitId"
            ></lf-unit-credits-table>
        </ng-template>
       </mat-tab>
  </mat-tab-group>

CSS
  :host {
     .lf-full-calendar {
     max-width: 1100px;
     display: block;
     margin-left: auto;
     margin-right: auto;
  }

 .google-calendar-title {
   font-size: 12px;
  }

 .google-calendar-list {
   display: flex;
  }

.google-calendar-container {
   display: flex;
   justify-content: space-between;
   max-width: 1100px;

select {
     background-color: #FFFFFF;
     font-size: 12px;
    min-width: 200px;
}

 .spinner {
    height: 30px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    }
   }
 }

 ::ng-deep {
    a.fc-daygrid-event {
  color: #ffffff;
}

.fc-daygrid-dot-event:hover {
    color: black;
   }
 }
 
@media print {
     .fc-daygrid-event {
         color:black !important;
     }
}


Is your browser set to not show some things (e.g. background color) and/or does this happen on a variety of browsers/OS?

Yes the browser is set to show everything. I was able to get the grid lines to show for the print but can't get the text to show black.

As you can now get the grid lines to show could you edit your question to remove that problem and show updated code (if relevant) and images, otherwise people may try to solve a problem for which you already have a solution.
